# Estoy obteniendo el error "invalid_grant / Invalid JWT Signature." al usar Oauth2 de Google

Tags: php, google-api, jwt, oauth2

Hace bastante tiempo que estoy luchando con este problema y ya no se por donde encararlo, necesito generar un access token con una cuenta de servicio para usar la api de Google Calendar. Lo primero que hago es generar el JWT (Json Web Token) con la libreria **firebase/php-jwt.** Luego de generar el JWT para enviar a Google hago un curl hacia Google para obtener dicho access token pero me arroja el error  "invalid_grant / Invalid JWT Signature."
Les dejo el ejemplo del la generacion del JWT

```
$time = time();

$key = file_get_contents("./certs/certificado.pem");
$token = array(
    "iss" => "*****@*******.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
    "iat" => $time,
    "exp" => $time+60,
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
echo $jwt;
print_r($decoded);

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
$grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

JWT::$leeway = 600; 
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

Ejemplo del CURL hacia Google.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=".urlencode($grant_type)."&assertion=".urlencode($jwt));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo($result);
```

Y la respuesta que obtengo del Curl es la siguiente

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```